# JQuery UI Datepicker not working inside asp:MutiView

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Coding with ASP.NET 3.5 C#, jquery.1.4.2, jquery-ui-1.8.2

My textbox is in fourth asp:View of an asp:MultiView which is not active on PageLoad.
My Page is also a content page with a master page. The textbox is created like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" 
        CssClass="datePicker" 
        MaxLength="20" 
        ReadOnly="true" 
        Width="70px" />
```

The datepicker is called like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datePicker').live('click', function () {
        $(this).datepicker({ 
            showOn: 'focus',
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            minDate: '+0d',
            maxDate: '+1y'
            });
    });
});
```

I am not able to get the datepicker on the first click of the textbox.
What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not showing the *first* time because the `focus` event has already fired, so you need to trigger it again so the `focus` fires and the datepicker shows, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datePicker').live('click', function () {
        $(this).datepicker({ 
            showOn: 'focus',
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            minDate: '+0d',
            maxDate: '+1y'
        }).focus();           //add this
    });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2MyxE/).  Calling [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) will fire the event once more, causing the datepicker handler on the event to fire, and it'll show, even the first click.